# Why am I getting the warning :Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized"?

Tags: java, android

I am getting warning in my `ListActivity`. The warning I am getting is shown below

- `Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be
  parameterized`

It is not creating any problems, but I would like to know why I am getting this warning and how to suppress it. See line which written within asterisks.

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity {

    String classes[]={"Second","example1","example2","example3","example4"}; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,classes));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String cheese=classes[position];
        try{
        **Class ourclass= Class.forName("com.app1."+cheese);**
        Intent ourintent= new Intent(Menu.this,ourclass);
        startActivity(ourintent);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27):

Class is generic, if you don't care for the warning you have two choices use `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` or my preference use the `<?>` (that is a [wildcard capture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html)) like this

```
Class<?> ourclass = Class.forName("com.app1."+cheese);
```

Comment: can anyone tell me the reason of that warning ?

Comment: Yes. Because the complete signature of [Class.forName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) is `public static Class<?> forName(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes","unchecked")`. You can also make the code

```
Class<?> ourclass= Class.forName("com.app1."+cheese);
```

to get rid of the warning. Now, you don't have to use `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")`. Compiler expects all the generic types to be parameterized

Answer (score 5):

To ignore the warning "Class is a raw type...." do the following inside eclipse*:

1. Click Window-Preferences-Java-Compiler-Errors/Warnings
2. Click "Generic Types"
3. Choose "Ignore" for "Usage of a Raw Type"
4. Click Apply
5. Click OK
6. Save and close your eclipse IDE

When you reopen eclipse, these specific warnings should no longer be listed.

*For this example solution I'm using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers - Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)